# Omnisharp not working on Manjaro Linux

Tags: .net-framework, c#, asp.net, core

today I've installed .NET Core 3.0 on my newly setup Manjaro system but I get an error everytime I want to open a Project with VS Code. The following is the output of "dotnet --info":

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   3.0.100 
>   Commit:    04339c3a26
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     manjaro  OS Version:    OS
>   Platform: Linux  RID:         linux-x64  Base Path:
>   /opt/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 3.0.0   Commit:  7d57652f33
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     3.0.100 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0
>   [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   3.0.0 [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Creating a project with

> dotnet new mvc -o MVCTest

works without a problem. But when I open such a project the following error message appears:

> Starting OmniSharp server at 11/8/2019, 3:29:18 PM
>       Target: /home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp
>
> OmniSharp server started.
>       Path: /home/lukask/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.6/.omnisharp/1.34.8-beta.2/run
>       PID: 3498
>
> [info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
>           Starting OmniSharp on manjaro 0.0 (x64) [info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
>           DotNetPath set to dotnet [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
>           Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
>               1: StandAlone 16.3 - "/home/lukask/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.6/.omnisharp/1.34.8-beta.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
>   [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
>           MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/lukask/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.6/.omnisharp/1.34.8-beta.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
>   [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
>           Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.3 - "/home/lukask/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.6/.omnisharp/1.34.8-beta.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
>               CscToolExe = csc.exe
>               MSBuildToolsPath = /home/lukask/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.6/.omnisharp/1.34.8-beta.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
>               CscToolPath = /home/lukask/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.6/.omnisharp/1.34.8-beta.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
>               BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
>               MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/lukask/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.6/.omnisharp/1.34.8-beta.2/omnisharp/.msbuild
>   [info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
>           Detecting Cake files in '/home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp'. [info]:
>   OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
>           Could not find any Cake files [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
>           No solution files found in '/home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp' [info]:
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Queue project update for '/home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj' [info]:
>   OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
>           Detecting CSX files in '/home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp'. [info]:
>   OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
>           Could not find any CSX files [info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
>   Order: 0 [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Loading project: /home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj [info]:
>   OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
>   Order: 100 [info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
>   Order: 200 [info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Configuration finished. [info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
>           Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp' on host 3290.   It was not
>   possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs   Did you mean to run
>   .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
>         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Failed to load project file '/home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj'.
>   /home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj(1,1)
>   Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK
>   'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found. 
>   /home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj   at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject
>   (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName,
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String
>   resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1]
>   (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName,
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String
>   resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1]
>   (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation,
>   System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned
>   (System.String directoryOfImportingFile,
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]&
>   projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult,
>   System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00254] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports
>   (System.String directoryOfImportingFile,
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027]
>   in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement
>   (System.String directoryOfImportingFile,
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement)
>   [0x0000d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass
>   (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement
>   currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in
>   <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService,
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
>   [0x0011c] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate
>   (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data,
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings,
>   System.Int32 maxNodeCount,
>   Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T]
>   environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService
>   loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T]
>   itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider
>   toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCache
>   projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext
>   buildEventContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService
>   sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext
>   evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x0002f] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService
>   loggingServiceForEvaluation,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext
>   evaluationContext) [0x0005e] in :0
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService
>   loggingServiceForEvaluation,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext
>   evaluationContext) [0x00035] in :0
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService
>   loggingServiceForEvaluation,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext
>   evaluationContext) [0x00000] in :0
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary
>   (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext
>   evaluationContext) [0x00007] in :0
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String
>   subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings
>   loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext
>   evaluationContext) [0x00126] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0
>
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String
>   projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String
>   subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection
>   projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings
>   loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext
>   evaluationContext) [0x00093] in :0
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String
>   projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String
>   subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection
>   projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings
>   loadSettings) [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion,
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection)
>   [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject
>   (System.String fileName,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject
>   (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String
>   filePath) [0x0003f] in <7795d04d64e84704911acc5f3dccb04a>:0    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath)
>   [0x0000d] in <7795d04d64e84704911acc5f3dccb04a>:0    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String
>   filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo,
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader) [0x00015] in
>   <7795d04d64e84704911acc5f3dccb04a>:0    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass29_0.b__0
>   () [0x00000] in <7795d04d64e84704911acc5f3dccb04a>:0    at (wrapper
>   delegate-invoke)
>   System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
>   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String
>   projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in
>   <7795d04d64e84704911acc5f3dccb04a>:0
>
> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/lukask/Projekte/Tests/TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj

I've already added "omnisharp.path": "latest" to my settings.json but that didn't change a thing.

Thank you very much for helping me!